# Dailymotion video upload using curl

Tags: curl, upload, dailymotion-api

I am trying to get video from google drive to daily motion using curl. i am new to this.

i first logged in using: curl --user name:password http://www.dailymotion.com/  then followed guide 
with this :

```
curl --request POST \

 --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
 --form 'url=<VIDEO_URL>' \
 --form 'title=Dailymotion cURL upload test' \
 --form 'tags=dailymotion,api,sdk,test' \
 --form 'channel=videogames' \
 --form 'published=true' \
 "api url"
```

but its giving me error "code":400,"message":"Invalid Authorization header format." Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you get the access token? Your code looks valid, but given the error message, your access token must not be ok. In the code you provide, you have to replace `${ACCESS_TOKEN}` by an actual access token.

To get an access token, you can:

- either follow this doc about authentication https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#authentication
- or you can simply test to create one from the API Explorer at https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl -v https://api.dailymotion.com/oauth/token \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  -d "client_id=<API_KEY>" \
  -d "client_secret=<API_SECRET>" \
  -d "username=<USER_USERNAME>" \
  -d "password=<USER_PASSWORD>"
```

Your ACCESS_TOKEN will be generated in json:

```
{
  "access_token": "YOUR ACCESS_TOKEN",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 36000,
  "refresh_token": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "scope": "read",
  "uid": "Your uid"
}
```

Copy the generated access_token field and use it for your mode.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR ACCESS_TOKEN" \
     "https://api.dailymotion.com/file/upload"
```